# How to take the derivative of multiple variables

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I am reading the article. They claimed that
[image]

I don't know how to obtain the last result.
Here is my attempt
$v(t,x) = e^{-ct}u(t,xe^{-ct})$, $u=u(t,w)$.
We have

$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}= -cv+e^{-ct} \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - cxe^{-2ct} \frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$.

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(cxv) = cv +cve^{-2ct}\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$.

That implies
$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial (cvx)}{\partial x}+v=e^{-ct}\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+u\right](t,xe^{-ct})=e^{-ct}\displaystyle \int_{xe^{-ct}}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{y} K_0 \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)u(t,y)dy$
By setting $y=ze^{-ct}$ we have that

$\displaystyle \int_{xe^{-ct}}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{y} K_0 \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)u(t,y)dy = \int_{x}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{z} K_0 \left(\frac{x}{ze^{-ct}}\right)v(t,z)dz$

I don't know how to continue

Thank you for your time. I appreciate your help.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative#Example

Comment: partial derivative is a derivation, you can act like it's a derivative in the variable $t$, the rest comes up with rules for derivation of a multiplication and derivation of a composition ($u \circ (t \mapsto (t,x e^{-ct})$) I believe it is called "chain rule for differential" in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will only explain how to compute the partial derivative, you should do the rest.

We set $\gamma: \begin{pmatrix}t \\ x  \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}t \\ x e^{-ct} \end{pmatrix}$. We have the Jacobian $J_\gamma = \begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 \\ -cxe^{-ct} & e^{-ct}\end{pmatrix}$.

We also have $J_u = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\end{pmatrix}$.

So $J_{u \circ \gamma} \left(\begin{pmatrix}t \\ x  \end{pmatrix}\right) = J_u \left(\gamma\begin{pmatrix}t \\ x  \end{pmatrix}\right) J_\gamma \left(\begin{pmatrix}t \\ x  \end{pmatrix}\right)
= \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\circ \gamma - cxe^{-ct} \cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \circ \gamma \\
e^{-ct} \cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \circ \gamma
\end{pmatrix}$

Thus
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} 
&= \frac{\partial }{\partial t} (e^{-ct}) u \circ \gamma + e^{-ct} \frac{\partial }{\partial t} (u \circ \gamma)
= -c v + e^{-ct} \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\circ \gamma - cxe^{-ct} \cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \circ \gamma \right) \end{align*}$$
and
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} 
&= e^{-ct} \frac{\partial }{\partial x} (u \circ \gamma) = e^{-2ct} \cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \circ \gamma   \end{align*}$$
You'll need $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(cxv) = cv + cx\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$

Comment: Could you please help me complete the rest?

Comment: Just compute the left term of the equality you wish to obtain it is direct

Comment: I am not familiar with working on union mapping. Could you please help me with this? This will be very useful for me.

Comment: This may sound harsh but if you can't manage to solve your problem after my help, you should consider working on more basic problems before reading such an article. If you really want to do it write it on a blank paper and do the math it will come up naturally.

Comment: Yes, I did but they also require to prove that $k_0 \left(\frac{x}{z} \right) = k_0 \left(\frac{x.e^{ct}}{z}\right)$ when $z \ge x$.

Comment: Ok what you can do is edit what you have already computed but if you have this property the result is just given by a variable change in the integral, but if you don't add what's new I can't help you

Comment: ok I will edit to add my attempt

Comment: I have added my attempt